# tab view ReactNative issue

Tags: react-native, tabview

I am having following issue I have added my code and screenshot. Can anyone guide me to solve this issue:

> Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `SceneView`.
>
> This error is located at:
>       
> in RCTView (at SceneView.tsx:92)
>       
> in SceneView (at TabView.tsx:181)
>       
> in RCTView (at createAnimatedComponent.js:233)
>       
> in AnimatedComponent(Component) (at Pager.tsx:780)
>       
> in PanGestureHandler (at Pager.tsx:769)
>       
> in Pager (at TabView.tsx:75)
>       
> in RCTView (at TabView.tsx:133)
>       
> in TabView (at Test.js:47)
>       
> in RCTView (at Test.js:46)
>       
> in Test (at SceneView.js:9)
>       
> in SceneView (at StackView.tsx:269)
>       
> in RCTView (at CardContainer.tsx:171)
>       
> in RCTView (at CardContainer.tsx:170)
>       
> in RCTView (at Card.tsx:488)
>       
> in RCTView (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
>       
> in AnimatedComponent (at Card.tsx:475)
>       
> in PanGestureHandler (at Card.tsx:468)
>       
> in RCTView (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
>       
> in AnimatedComponent (at Card.tsx:464)
>       
> in RCTView (at Card.tsx:457)
>       
> in Card (at CardContainer.tsx:138)
>       
> in CardContainer (at CardStack.tsx:544)
>       
> in RCTView (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
>       
> in AnimatedComponent (at CardStack.tsx:121)
>       
> in MaybeScreen (at CardStack.tsx:537)
>       
> in RCTView (at CardStack.tsx:96)
>       
> in MaybeScreenContainer (at CardStack.tsx:444)
>       
> in CardStack (at StackView.tsx:377)
>       
> in KeyboardManager (at StackView.tsx:375)
>       
> in SafeAreaProviderCompat (at StackView.tsx:372)
>       
> in StackView (at StackView.tsx:41)
>       
> in StackView (at createStackNavigator.tsx:33)
>       
> in Unknown (at createNavigator.js:80)
>       
> in Navigator (at SceneView.js:9)
>       
> in SceneView (at StackView.tsx:269)
>       
> in RCTView (at CardContainer.tsx:171)
>       
> in RCTView (at CardContainer.tsx:170)
>       
> in RCTView (at Card.tsx:488)
>       
> in RCTView (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
>       
> in AnimatedComponent (at Card.tsx:475)
>       
> in PanGestureHandler (at Card.tsx:468)
>       
> in RCTView (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
>       
> in AnimatedComponent (at Card.tsx:464)
>       
> in RCTView (at Card.tsx:457)
>       
> in Card (at CardContainer.tsx:138)
>       
> in CardContainer (at CardStack.tsx:544)
>       
> in RCTView (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
>       
> in AnimatedComponent (at CardStack.tsx:121)
>       
> in MaybeScreen (at CardStack.tsx:537)
>       
> in RCTView (at CardStack.tsx:96)
>       
> in MaybeScreenContainer (at CardStack.tsx:444)
>       
> in CardStack (at StackView.tsx:377)
>       
> in KeyboardManager (at StackView.tsx:375)
>       
> in RNCSafeAreaView (at src/index.tsx:26)
>       
> in SafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaProviderCompat.tsx:34)
>       
> in SafeAreaProviderCompat (at StackView.tsx:372)
>       
> in StackView (at StackView.tsx:41)
>       
> in StackView (at createStackNavigator.tsx:33)
>       
> in Unknown (at createNavigator.js:80)
>       
> in Navigator (at createAppContainer.js:430)
>       
> in NavigationContainer (at App.js:20)
>       
> in App (at renderApplication.js:40)
>       
> in RCTView (at AppContainer.js:101)
>       
> in RCTView (at AppContainer.js:119)
>       
> in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)
>
> index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:27606:43
>   createFiberFromTypeAndProps
>       
> index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:27608:19
>   createFiberFromElement
>       
> index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:27628:48
>   reconcileSingleElement
>       
> index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:19154:51
>   reconcileChildFibers
>       
> index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:19201:63
>   reconcileChildren
>       
> index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:21139:50
>   updateHostComponent
>       
> index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:21533:26
>   invokeGuardedCallbackImpl
>       
> index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:12669:21
>   invokeGuardedCallback
>       
> index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:12765:42
>   beginWork$$1
>       
> index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:26886:34
>   performUnitOfWork
>       
> index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:26024:30
>   workLoopSync
>       
> index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:26006:45
>   renderRoot
>       
> index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:25770:29
>   renderRoot
>       
> [native code]:0
>   runRootCallback
>       
> index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:25531:34
>   runRootCallback
>       
> [native code]:0
>   
>       
> index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:16261:38
>   unstable_runWithPriority
>       
> index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:42653:30
>   flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl
>       
> index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:16256:28
>   flushSyncCallbackQueue
>       
> index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:16245:35
>   scheduleUpdateOnFiber
>       
> index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:25413:37
>   scheduleRootUpdate
>       
> index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:27838:21
>   scheduleRoot
>       
> index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:16809:42
>   
>       
> index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:41056:35
>   forEach
>       
> [native code]:0
>   performReactRefresh
>       
> index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:41048:30
>   performReactRefresh
>       
> index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:40854:48
>   
>       
> index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:480:40
>   _callTimer
>       
> index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:30628:17
>   callTimers
>       
> index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:30835:19
>   __callFunction
>       
> index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:2681:49
>   
>       
> index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:2394:31
>   __guard
>       
> index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:2635:15
>   callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
>       
> index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:2393:21
>   callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
>       
> [native code]:0

[image]

**Code:**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet, SafeAreaView, Text, Button} from 'react-native';
import {
  TabViewAnimated,
  TabView,
  TabViewPage,
  TabBarTop,
} from 'react-native-tab-view';

export default class Test extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      index: 0,
      routes: [
        {key: '1', title: 'First'},
        {key: '2', title: 'Second'},
      ],
    };
  }

  _renderScene = ({route}) => {
    switch (route.key) {
      case '1':
        return <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#ff4081'}} />;
      case '2':
        return <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#673ab7'}} />;
      default:
        return null;
    }
  };

  _renderPage = props => (
    <TabViewPage {...props} renderScene={this._renderScene} />
  );

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TabView
          navigationState={this.state}
          renderScene={this._renderPage}
          renderHeader={this._renderHeader}
          onIndexChange={index => this.setState({index})}
          style={styles.container}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I have added snapshot and code. Please guide me how to resolve it.

Comment: _You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports._ Did you check if one of those is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the Component's context is not available in `_renderPage()`. As you are calling `this._renderScene` in renderPage, it needs to be aware of the context / this to find the specific function. Whenever you are giving a function from your class component to another component, you need to also tell that it should inherit the component's context.

You can do this via bindings (`renderScene={this._renderPage}` to `renderScene={this._renderPage.bind(this)}`) or specify an anonymous function (`renderScene={(data) => this._renderPage(data)}`).